# How to generate load testing reports using jmeter?

Tags: testing, load, report, jmeter

I have performed a load test using JMETER.
But now not able to generate reports for the test.

To generate report I have followed these steps:

1. Create a new variable JAVA_HOME in the environment variable and set the path for the JDK.
2. Create another variable ANT_HOME and set the path for the Apache-ant.
3. Create another variable PATH and set the path for apache-ant up to BIN folder.
4. Place the `ant-jmeter-1.0.9.jar` file in side ‘Extras’ folder. Which is located in the path jakarta-jmeter-2.3.2->extras
5. Navigate to the ‘build.xml’ folder of the jmeter which is located in the path jakarta-jmeter-2.3.2->extras->build.xml.
6. Set the `classpathref = “D:\loadtest\jakarta-jmeter-2.4\extras\ant-jmeter-1.0.9.jar “`
7. Set `jmeterhome=”D:\loadtest\jakarta-jmeter-2.4″`
8. Set `style=”D:\loadtest\jakarta-jmeter-2.4\jmeter-results-detail-report${style_version}.xsl”` and save it.
9. Now copy jmx file and the build.xml file put it in a folder (Loadtest) where ever you want to generate the report.
10. Open command prompt and navigate to the folder where jmx and build file is located.
11. To run a test and create the output report:
    Type the command “`ant -Dtest=script”`(for eg. I have my test.jms file and the command is `ant -Dtest=test`)

By following above steps Reports are not generated but I got following error:

`BUILD FAILED`

```
D:\Loadtest\result\build.xml:85: Reference D:/Loadtest/jakarta-jmeter-2.4/
extras/ant-jmeter.jar not found.
```

Can you help me find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Check jMeter version. The error says you're using 2.4, but your Jmeter home points to 2.3.2.

Comment: Hey mbonaci, Thanks for reply. that was mistake of mine in the question,I have corrected that. I am using the `jakarta-jmeter-2.4` version

Answer (score 0):

Did you include ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar in your Ant classpath ? Adding the jar to $ANT_HOME/lib will make this happen automatically.

See:

- http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php

ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar is in jmeter/extras folder.

Furthermore I suggest you upgrade to last JMeter 2.7 version as it contains enhancements of the report.

Regards

Philippe M.

http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/-Solutions-